Inset on text faces not giving desired result!

I need to inset the texts and give it a depth, but I am not able to do so because the edges are flowing in their respective normal directions instead of joining the vertices of the inset face with a proper edge flow which is resulting in so much of faces intersections. If this was a simple shape, I could just have scaled it down, but it won't work in this case. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here. Or if there is an alternative way of getting the desired result, please tell me, it would be a great help. I am following a tutorial which was created in 3DS Max and there was no problem while inseting text in 3DS Max.

I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

I would bridge the two sides (that would need some topology working, can be done by parts) and then add loopcuts with an even profile. Or just adjust and merge the few vertices that are out of place with the inset.

@DanielMöller I'm curious as to where it came from in the first place! If it was a simple Text object I'd have used Object > Convert to Mesh and then in Edit mode Mesh > Clean Up > Limited Dissolve. You can then inset the face with no problem.

@JohnEason Yes, it is a text object converted to mesh. I have created the text in fast editing mode from the text properties which gave me only the outline edges of the text (because I didn't want the triangulated faces), then I filled it with a single ngon face. The limited dissolve is however worked in my case as it is dissolving some vertices in the dense corners without changing the shape of the text. Thanks for the help.

Not sure what you mean by "fast edit mode" because just converting from Text to mesh gives a face that's already filled in, but glad it helped!
